# Confused on how to extract multiple data values with a single regular expression

Tags: python

I have a text file with text that looks like this:

```
(49) Sat Jun/30 21:00        Uruguay     2-1 (1-0)   Portugal       @ Fisht Stadium, Sochi (UTC+3)
[Edinson Cavani 7', 62'; Pepe 55']
```

I have to implement a generator function that extracts data from each line of text according to these rules

-read from the input file the 2 lines of text for one game

-use 2 regular expressions (1 for each line) to extract the data (color coded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8iZA.png)) for one Game object

-pass back the data (Note that the extracted data are passed back, don't pass back a Game object)

I can extract 1 data value, but I'm having trouble with extracting 5 data values(Game Number, Country1/2, Score1/2) from a line of text with just one regular expression.

Comment: [Can you please post the text file as text not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you show the regex you've tried for each line?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! If I'm trying to obtain the country, I could do \s{8}\w+\s+ for example. But I don't know how I'm supposed to extract multiple data values with just 1 regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
with open('FileName.txt','r') as f:
   print([{'Game Number':line.split()[0],'Country 1':line.split()[4],'Country 2':line.split()[7],'Score 1':line.split()[5], 'Score 2':line.split()[6]} if not line[0]=='[' else {'Player Name':[re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\s+]','',i).strip() for i in line.split(';')], 'Minute':[[int(re.sub('\D','',x)) for x in i.split() if any(a for a in x if a.isdigit())] for i in line.split(';')]} for line in f])
```